# Script not running hidden

Tags: powershell, wsh

The following script will run if I run it minimized but not if I run it hidden. What am I doing wrong?

```
        #The intention of this script is to function as a keepalive.
        #The command used to run it in a hidden state is
        #powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden c:\psscript\keepalive.ps1

        # How long to run script(1)=infinite
        while (1) {
        $wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
        # Enter the keystrokes to be sent between the {}
        $wsh.SendKeys('{SCROLLLOCK}')
        # Time between keystrokes
        Start-Sleep -seconds 600
          }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell - Keyboard keystroke in a Hidden Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996201/powershell-keyboard-keystroke-in-a-hidden-windows)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this. This code runs fine while hidden, but it will only run once. I know this because I just tested it. What are you trying to accomplish by this?